# Selection sort: When using selection sort, how many times longer will sorting a list of 30 elements take compared to sorting a list of 6 elements?

Tags: computer-science

When using selection sort, how many times longer will sorting a list of 30 elements take compared to sorting a list of 6 elements?

Answer (score 0):

Selection sort is O(N^2).  How much bigger is 30 than 6?  Square it.